# PHP - date modify returned negative Microseconds

Tags: php

It appears that rarely I'm getting a negative microseconds datetime.

`$next_datetime = date_create()->modify('-500 ms')->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");`

// Output "2023-05-30 18:57:50.-99999"

Running PHP 8.1

Can anyone explain this?

*** UPDATE ***

This only happens when the datetime microseconds is set to one.

`

```
        $datetime_before = date_create('now');

        $datetime_before->setTime(1,1,1,1  /* If set to any other number, it works fine */);

        $datetime_after  = clone($datetime_before);

        $datetime_after->modify('-100 ms');

        $string   = $datetime_after->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');

        if (str_contains($string, "-999")) {
            echo 'before: ';
            var_dump($datetime_before);
            echo PHP_EOL;

            echo 'after: ';
            var_dump($datetime_after);
            echo PHP_EOL;
            exit;
        }
```

`

Output

`before: object(DateTime)#51 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2023-06-02 01:01:01.000001" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" } after: object(DateTime)#52 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2023-06-02 01:01:01.-99999" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" }`

Example:
https://3v4l.org/YDEq2#v8.1.19

Comment: I've updated my post. I've managed to replicate it.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it feels like a PHP bug--some IEEE-754 floating point precision issue that only happens in some precise microsecond and is not handled nicely by either formatting function (implicit var_dump() or explicit format()).

Comment: Updated it again, and it happens every time.

Comment: There are a lot of checks for the literal `-99999` in the [php_date.c source code file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5fae4b50318faf3c3011cb4b24cceb3926b2ba84/ext/date/php_date.c#L3116). Looks very suspicious that a case might be missing...

Comment: Tried it using mircoseconds instead of milliseconds, so ->modify('-100000 μs'). Same awkward result containing negative microseconds.
@Progman might be right. Hours, minutes and seconds get set to 0, if value is -99999. But not the microseconds.

Comment: Looks like this bug was introduced in PHP 7.2. Same code giving correct result in PHP 7.1.x

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug ([GH-11368](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/11368)), fixed in [PHP/8.2.9](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.2.9) (released on 3 August 2023).

Answer (score -2):

Based on https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php I think your time format is wrong. ms is something that doesn’t seem to be part of a supported format. On your case you would need frac

My guess would be that php would interpret it as month and leap seconds.

Comment: I believe I'm using the correct format: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: You're linking to the format() function supported formats. The link I've provided is found in the https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php page where the modify() method is described.

Comment: The page you link belongs to [Supported Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), and documents the formats that PHP understand when parsing from strings: "This section describes all the different formats in a BNF-like format, that the DateTimeImmutable, DateTime, date_create_immutable(), date_create(), date_parse(), and strtotime() parser understands." - Reference for `->format()` is shown right at [DateTimeInterface::format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) and includes `u` for Microseconds.